# Laravel multiple conditions outer left join with external variables

Tags: mysql, laravel, left-join, outer-join

Good morming, I have the following multiple join. I want it as left outer. It is not working for me...because it is changing outer join to inner.

```
$query=DB::Table("Users")->select("Users.*","Strings.Text as Title","Strings2.Text as Name" ,"Strings3.Text as Description", "Strings4.Text as Summary")
    ->join("Strings",function($join) use($bbddlang)
        {
            $join->on("Users.HeroTitle","Strings.StringID");
            $join->where("Strings.Lang",$bbddlang);
        }, "left outer")
    ->join("Strings as Strings2",function($join) use($bbddlang)
        {
            $join->on("Users.HeroName","Strings2.StringID");
            $join->where("Strings2.Lang",$bbddlang);
        }, "left outer")
    ->join("Strings as Strings3",function($join) use($bbddlang)
        {
            $join->on("Users.Description","Strings3.StringID");
            $join->where("Strings3.Lang",$bbddlang);
        }, "left outer")
    ->join("Strings as Strings4",function($join) use($bbddlang)
        {
            $join->on("Users.Summary","Strings4.StringID");
            $join->where("Strings4.Lang",$bbddlang);
        }, "left outer")
    ->where("Strings.Text",$hero);
```

This is what I get using ToSql() method:

```
select `Users`.*, `Strings`.`Text` as `Title`, `Strings2`.`Text` as `Name`, `Strings3`.`Text` as `Description`, `Strings4`.`Text` as `Summary` 
from `Users` 
inner join `Strings` 
    on `Users`.`HeroTitle` = `Strings`.`StringID` 
    and `Strings`.`Lang` = ? 
inner join `Strings` as `Strings2` 
    on `Users`.`HeroName` = `Strings2`.`StringID` 
    and `Strings2`.`Lang` = ? 
inner join `Strings` as `Strings3` 
  on `Users`.`Description` = `Strings3`.`StringID` 
      and `Strings3`.`Lang` = ? 
inner join `Strings` as `Strings4` 
  on `Users`.`Summary` = `Strings4`.`StringID` 
      and `Strings4`.`Lang` = ? 
where `Strings`.`Text` = ?
```

(The ? are the external variables to the query, thats not the problem).

When it is a single condition, it is like this

```
->join('answers as answers', 'responses.answer_id', '=', 'answers.id', 'left outer')
```

I have tried with leftjoin, and it replaces the inner join to left join, but passing the parameter to outer is again useless... since the outer doesn't appear in query.

My question is why is it ignoring the "outer join" parameter passed?. Do I miss another parameter when second join parameter is a function?

Comment: use `leftjoin()` instead

Comment: used, but i'm asking about outer ... and asking about why is it ignoring the parameter

Comment: Because `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN` are the same.

Comment: I was using leftjoin already, I just wanted to know the reason, and now it is answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [join-function-source-code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L343)

> join(string $table, string $first, string|null $operator = null, string|null $second = null, string $type = 'inner', bool $where = false)

`$first` can be instance of Closure, so when you are using closure as second parameter, `"left join"` as third parameter to `$operator`, `$type` has the default value `"inner"`. That's why the raw sql always return `inner join ...`.

You need put the `LEFT OUTER` in 5th position:

```php
->join("Strings", function($join) use($bbddlang)
        {
            $join->on("Users.HeroTitle","Strings.StringID");
            $join->where("Strings.Lang",$bbddlang);
        },  null, null, "left outer")
```

So recommend to use `leftjoin` with Closure instead of `join`

```php
->leftjoin("Strings", function($join) use($bbddlang)
        {
            $join->on("Users.HeroTitle","Strings.StringID");
            $join->where("Strings.Lang",$bbddlang);
        })
```

Comment: Thanks TsaiKoga, your solution worked for me. If we have multiple parameters to use them in the join function then we can do it like `->leftjoin("Strings", function($join) use($bbddlang1, $bbddlang2, $bbddlang3)`. Thanks.